# SVG - Clicking out from the masking area of an image keep triggering the click on that image

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg

I have an SVG with two images inside. Each image is masked. I have the image 1 on top and the image 2 below. The image 2 if not masked reach the bottom half of the masked area of image 1 as you can see on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUIfm.png).

Then I have attached a click listener to both images.

My problem is that when they both are masked, if I do click on the bottom half of image 1 then the click event of the image 2 is triggered. I think this is because if the images are not masked, part of the image 2 is visible also overlapping the bottom half of the image 1. But I don't understand why because they both are masked when this happens.

Here I leave you a JSFiddle with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/pfwj5bpp/). I hope it can help you to understand better what's happening.

**HTML**

```
<div style="display:inline-block;width:155px;height:600px;float:left;">
    <svg class="side" width="155" height="600" style="stroke-width:0px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:1;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.2">
        <defs>
            <mask id="mask_image_001"><ellipse style="fill:#ffffff;" cx="75.54" cy="277.19" rx="50.49" ry="32.28"/></mask>
            <mask id="mask_image_002"><circle style="fill:#ffffff;" cx="98.34" cy="365.73" r="39.56"/></mask>
        </defs>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="155" height="600" style="fill:#ffffff;"/>
        <g class="board">
            <g id="group_image_001" mask="url(#mask_image_001)"><image id="image_1" width="3000" height="2000" xlink:href="http://i74.imgup.net/image_a3f72.jpg" orig_x="0" orig_y="0" class=" cursor_move" style="opacity: 1;" transform="matrix(0.13561538461538464,-0.03307692307692302,0.03307692307692302,0.13561538461538464,-231,276.9999999999998)"/></g>
            <g id="group_image_002" mask="url(#mask_image_002)"><image id="image_2" width="3338" height="4550" xlink:href="http://d16.imgup.net/image_b28d1.jpg" orig_x="0" orig_y="0" class=" cursor_move" style="opacity: 1;" transform="matrix(0.06248572762902408,-0.00009288817017963043,0.00009288817017963043,0.06248572762902408,-23.9999999999997,277)"/></g>
        </g>
        <image class="bg noevents" xlink:href="http://k81.imgup.net/backgrounddb78.png" x="0" y="0" width="155" height="600"/>
        <g id="paths_handlers">
            <ellipse id="path_image_001" class="path_image noevents" rel="#mask_image_001" style="stroke:none;fill:transparent;" cx="75.54" cy="277.19" rx="50.49" ry="32.28"/>
            <circle id="path_image_002" class="path_image noevents" rel="#mask_image_002" style="stroke:none;fill:transparent;" cx="98.34" cy="365.73" r="39.56"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;float:left;">
    <input type="button" class="button_switch_background" value="Switch Background" style="margin-bottom:6px;" /><br />
    <input type="button" class="button_switch_mask" value="Switch Mask Image 2" style="margin-bottom:6px;" /><br />
    Clicked: <span class="status"></span>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var colors = ["#c00", "#0c0", "#00c"];
var color_index = 0;
$(function(){
    $(".button_switch_background").click(function(){
        // just switching the background
        var t = "url(#mask_image_002)";
        if ($("svg .bg").css("display") != "none")
            $("svg .bg").css({display: "none"});
        else
            $("svg .bg").css({display: ""});
    });
    $(".button_switch_mask").click(function(){
        // just switching the mask
        var t = "url(#mask_image_002)";
        $("#group_image_002").attr("mask", ($("#group_image_002").attr("mask") == t)? "_"+t: t);
    });
    $("svg image").click(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
        $(".status").html($(this).attr("id")).css({color: colors[(color_index++)%3]});
    });
})
```

**CSS**

```
* { font-family: Arial; }
.noevents {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

**MY GOAL:** In case both images are already masked... I want when I click on the bottom half of the image 1, the click event of image 1 be triggered and NOT the click event of image 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the SVG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#interact-PointerEventsProperty), pixels that appear transparent due to a mask, are *not* considered transparent with respect to pointer events.

> a mask is not a binary transition, but a pixel operation, and different behavior for fully transparent and almost-but-not-fully-transparent may be confusingly arbitrary; as a consequence, for elements with a mask applied, pointer-events must still be captured even in areas where the mask goes to zero opacity.

If you want clicks to be able to pass through the invisible areas of the image, then you should switch to using a `<clipPath>` instead.  You should then have the behaviour you desire.